# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings sql-server 2008

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, sql-server-2008

I can't connect to database. i have these extension `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64.dll`, `php_sqlsrv_72_ts_x64` and added "extension = php_sqlsrv_72...." line in `php.ini` file. What am i doing wrong?

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename:
>   C:/Apache24/htdocs/smartattendanceciwec/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 436

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'password',
    'database' => 'Hospital',
    'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: my way of asking question. Is it wrong?

Comment: How you connect that MsSQL using SQL Managment studio? What's the host configuration?  I think `hostname`should be like `{yourIPxxx.xx.xx.xx}\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: nope didn't work

Comment: 192.168.1.200\sqlexpress,1433 no result

Comment: When you connect with SQL management studio, what's the host?

Answer (score 1):

what you are missing is odbc driver in your system.
beacuse you are using server 2008 R2 you will need to install odbc driver 11
you can download it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, what I need was the ODBC driver.